# jQuery slider does not work on Chrome (with interval)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-slider

I have a slider which is made by jQuery. It uses next and previous buttons to slide and it has automatic sliding feature with setInterval method.It works on Internet Explorer and Firefox but not on Chrome.How can I solve this problem.T

My little project is [here](http://www.filedropper.com/slider).

Comment: @abatishchev thanks for editing.Sorry for my wrongs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because when you do

```
var totalLi = $("#s li").length;
var liWidth = $("#s li").width();
var totalWidth = totalLi * liWidth;
$("#s").css("width", totalWidth);
```

`images` are not loaded, and browser does not know its width and width of `li` elements, so `$("#s li").width()` provides `0`.

For example if you will write

```
var liWidth = $("#s").width();
```

instead of

```
var liWidth = $("#s li").width();
```

then it will works, because browser know `#s` element width from css.

Comment: Thanks @Speransky Danil.It would be very hard to solve without ur helps.

Comment: Ok this time it was working badly on IE but I solved with browser dedecting

                  if( $.browser.chrome){
           liWidth=$("#s").width();
     }

               if($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.msie){
     liWidth=$("#s li").width();
     }

Comment: Your html file which is in depositfiles.com does not work on IE nicely.So I am using this code instead of browser dedection if dedection is not legal.

var liWidth=$("#s li").width();
  
 if( liWidth==0){
           liWidth=$("#s").width();
        }

Comment: You have said that .width method return 0.Then,I check this to solve.Is there anything illegal here ?